# Scroll automatically to the bottom page - speed control

Tags: javascript

I need your help on my site for the issue of "Scroll automatically to the bottom of the page"

I am currently using the script below to control the auto scroll page, but the only thing is I do not know how to control the scroll speed. Can someone help please?

```
 window.onload=toBottom;

function toBottom()
{
window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);
}
```

And my site url is : http://worldplatter.com/2014/recipe/beef/

Comment: You had to do it in steps or use jQuery [`animate()`](http://api.jquery.com/animate/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use jQuery animate function to scroll the page as you have used jQuery Library in your site like below :

```
 jQuery(window).load(function() {
    jQuery("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: jQuery(document).height() }, 1000);
 });
```

Comment: @SkyYau, Glad i could help. Can you please accept my answer if it's really helps to you.